# Estoy usando pandas en python con VScode y no veo los resultados de lo que debe hacer el programa

Tags: python, pandas, vscode

[image: Este es el código que estoy usando]

[image: Esto es lo que me devuelve salida]
al ejecutar el programa deberían salirme los datos guardados en el csv de forma organizada pero sin embargo no hace nada y pone DONE en salida.

Comment: Revisa qué terminal estás usando, si es la de shell que abre por defecto entonces es el comportamiento normal, según recuerdo hay un plug-in que habilita una terminal para python

Comment: Seria ideal que cambie  esa imagenes a código

Comment: Buenas, el codigo es correcto. Deberias de probar a correrlo en otra consola externa a vscode